# Use Jquery .toggle in rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery

I've been trying to get the .toggle function of Jquery to work in a rails 3.1 app such that a user can click a link to either show or hide content on the page they're viewing.

The functionality I'm trying to replicate is the same as the example shown here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

---

```
<script>
$("button").click(function () {
$("p").toggle();
});
```

In my rails app, I have a users.js file found in app/assets/javascripts. The file only contains the following code:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$('.cell').toggle();
});
```

The view then has the following code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="cell" style="display: none">
Some info
</td>
<td class="cell">
Other info
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Show/hide" />
```

When I load the page, the button shows up along with the 'Other info', but when I click the button, no action it taken and nothing changes. When I inspect the source code of the page, it is definitely including my users.js file in the header.

For some reason the javascript code won't execute the toggle and change the page content. I don't know if this is a Rails 3.1 issue, or not. Using a small standalone app, this functionality works fine when I include the script manually at the bottom of the page like:

```
<script>

$("#button").click(function(){
$(".cell").toggle();
});

</script>
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong with the jquery code or rails configuration?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The markup and js code is solid, it should work.

Open your javascript console and see what errors are produced. Is jQuery being loaded in your rails layout?

Comment: See comment above - seems that $("#button") is coming out as null. Do you know what that would mean? Is it not able to find the 'button' attribute on my page for some reason?

Comment: Try using a `class` instead of an `id`, and try renaming `button` to `my-button`. Sometimes weird copy-and-paste errors sneak up on you. Are you definitely using jQuery, and not Prototype? Type `$().jquery` in the console to see what version is loaded.

Comment: Hi there - thanks again for your attempts at helping. I believe the issue was being caused by a few legacy files I had copied over from my rails 3.0 app - namely protoype.js, effect.js, controls.js and dragdrop.js... it seems they were breaking the functionality on the page. I removed them from my assets/javascripts folder and things seem to work now. Again - thanks for the help!

Comment: That's great Cam! Make sure to upvote or accept the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#button").live('click', function(e){
  $(".cell").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks - was worth a try but didn't work. When I review the web console for errors, I see that $("button") is null - not sure why it would be evaluated as null though. It also says 'Effect is not defined' and 'Prototype' is not defined. But I'm pretty sure it's loading Jquery properly as it is one of the files loaded from my rails assets folders. Any other thoughts?

Comment: wrong usage it is not  $("button"), use either  $("#button") or  $("input#button") @Chris did it correctlly

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and it seems as though the users.js file is referencing elements in the DOM that haven't been loaded yet. Putting the JavaScript at the bottom solves this, but using [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) seems to make the code work even when it's placed in the .js file.

Put this in your users.js file and see if it solves the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('.cell').toggle();
    });
});
```

You can also do this with CoffeeScript (users.js.coffee):

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('#button').click ->
        $('.cell').toggle()
```